# Unity C# - How continue playing an animation from the point it stopped

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So in Unity I have a simple script that detects weather or not the player presses W or S and if they do then play a walking animation. And it works just fine, but if I stop moving and the animation is half way through playing and I press W or S it will restart the animation from the beginning of the animation not the current point it was stopped at, is there a way to make it play from that point, here is the code:

```
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        animation.Play("Walking");
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
    {
        animation.Play("Walking");
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.W))
    {
        animation.Stop();
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.S))
    {
        animation.Stop();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I simply made it change speeds instead of using start and stop:

```
    animation.Play();
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        animation["Walking"].speed = 1;
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
    {
        animation["Walking"].speed = -1;
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.W))
    {
        animation["Walking"].speed = 0;
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.S))
    {
        animation["Walking"].speed = 0;
    }
```

Comment: that doesn't look like it'll work in the case where two keys are pressed, or when i let one of my two keys go.  I'd have to release both keys and then re-press one to get movement back.